# Ansible to access Github: become causes Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, public-key, github, ansible-playbook

## Objective

Would like to understand the mechanism why using ***become*** to be the ansible user causes "Permission denied (publickey)".

User ***ansible*** to run ansible-playbook to checkout a Github repository. SSH keys have been copied with ssh-copy-id with the user.

Without ***become***, the playbook runs.

```
[ansible@ip-172-31-39-108 playbooks]$ whoami
ansible

[ansible@ip-172-31-39-108 playbooks]$ ansible-playbook git.yml
PLAY [Git example] *************************************************************
TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [ub01]
TASK [check out the repository on the host] ************************************
changed: [ub01]
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
ub01                       : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

However, using ***"become: yes"*** causes the error.

```
[ansible@ip-172-31-39-108 playbooks]$ ansible-playbook git.yml
PLAY [Git example] *************************************************************
TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [ub01]
TASK [check out the repository on the host] ************************************
fatal: [ub01]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/git clone --origin origin '' /home/ansible/project/mezzanine-example", "failed": true, "msg": "Cloning into '/home/ansible/project/mezzanine-example'...\nPermission denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.", "rc": 128, "stderr": "Cloning into '/home/ansible/project/mezzanine-example'...\nPermission denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/ansible/playbooks/git.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
ub01                       : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

ssh-agent is running and the private key has been added.

```
[ansible@ip-172-31-39-108 playbooks]$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 1513

[ansible@ip-172-31-39-108 playbooks]$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Identity added: /home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

### Question

Please provide explanations why this happen or point to the resource to look into.

Also I only started ssh-agent in the server that runs ansible-playbook, but not on the target server. How the Github SSH authentication happens on the target server?

### Playbook

```
- name: Git example
  hosts: webservers
  become: no    # <----- Changing to yes cause the issue
  become_user: ansible
  become_method: sudo
  vars:
    repo_url: git@github.com:lorin/mezzanine-example.git
    proj_dirname: /home/ansible/project
    proj_name: mezzanine-example
    proj_path: "{{ proj_dirname }}/{{ proj_name }}"
  tasks:
    - name: check out the repository on the host
      git: repo={{ repo_url }} dest={{ proj_path }} accept_hostkey=yes
```

### Configurations

**hosts**

```
[webservers]
ub01
#rh01
```

**ansible.cfg**

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ForwardAgent=yes
```

### Environment

Ansible playbook is run on RedHat.

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.3 (Maipo)"
```

The target host is Ubuntu.

```
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
```

### Related Issues

- [Ansible with Github: Permission denied (Publickey)](https://serverfault.com/questions/735651/ansible-with-github-permission-denied-publickey/746287)
- [How to fix "Permission denied (publickey)." Ansible and "git clone" issue](https://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/754-how-to-fix-permission-denied-publickey-ansible-and-git-clone-issue)
- [Accessing SSH_AUTH_SOCK from another non-root user](https://serverfault.com/questions/442048/accessing-ssh-auth-sock-from-another-non-root-user)

### Console -vvvvv output

```
TASK [check out the repository on the host] ************************************
task path: /home/ansible/playbooks/git.yml:12
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/source_control/git.py
<ub01> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<ub01> SSH: ansible.cfg set ssh_args: (-o)(ControlMaster=auto)(-o)(ControlPersist=60s)(-o)(ForwardAgent=yes)
<ub01> SSH: ansible_password/ansible_ssh_pass not set: (-o)(KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no)(-o)(PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey)(-o)(PasswordAuthentication=no)
<ub01> SSH: ANSIBLE_TIMEOUT/timeout set: (-o)(ConnectTimeout=10)
<ub01> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_common_args: ()
<ub01> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_extra_args: ()
<ub01> SSH: found only ControlPersist; added ControlPath: (-o)(ControlPath=/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r)
<ub01> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ForwardAgent=yes -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r ub01 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1485919043.94-240537002849590 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1485919043.94-240537002849590="` echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1485919043.94-240537002849590 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<ub01> PUT /tmp/tmpAjaOMc TO /tmp/ansible-tmp-1485919043.94-240537002849590/git.py
<ub01> SSH: ansible.cfg set ssh_args: (-o)(ControlMaster=auto)(-o)(ControlPersist=60s)(-o)(ForwardAgent=yes)
<ub01> SSH: ansible_password/ansible_ssh_pass not set: (-o)(KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no)(-o)(PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey)(-o)(PasswordAuthentication=no)
<ub01> SSH: ANSIBLE_TIMEOUT/timeout set: (-o)(ConnectTimeout=10)
<ub01> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_common_args: ()
<ub01> SSH: PlayContext set sftp_extra_args: ()
<ub01> SSH: found only ControlPersist; added ControlPath: (-o)(ControlPath=/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r)
<ub01> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ForwardAgent=yes -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r '[ub01]'
<ub01> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<ub01> SSH: ansible.cfg set ssh_args: (-o)(ControlMaster=auto)(-o)(ControlPersist=60s)(-o)(ForwardAgent=yes)
<ub01> SSH: ansible_password/ansible_ssh_pass not set: (-o)(KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no)(-o)(PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey)(-o)(PasswordAuthentication=no)
<ub01> SSH: ANSIBLE_TIMEOUT/timeout set: (-o)(ConnectTimeout=10)
<ub01> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_common_args: ()
<ub01> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_extra_args: ()
<ub01> SSH: found only ControlPersist; added ControlPath: (-o)(ControlPath=/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r)
<ub01> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ForwardAgent=yes -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r ub01 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'setfacl -m u:ansible:r-x /tmp/ansible-tmp-1485919043.94-240537002849590/ /tmp/ansible-tmp-1485919043.94-240537002849590/git.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<ub01> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<ub01> SSH: ansible.cfg set ssh_args: (-o)(ControlMaster=auto)(-o)(ControlPersist=60s)(-o)(ForwardAgent=yes)
<ub01> SSH: ansible_password/ansible_ssh_pass not set: (-o)(KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no)(-o)(PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey)(-o)(PasswordAuthentication=no)
<ub01> SSH: ANSIBLE_TIMEOUT/timeout set: (-o)(ConnectTimeout=10)
<ub01> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_common_args: ()
<ub01> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_extra_args: ()
<ub01> SSH: found only ControlPersist; added ControlPath: (-o)(ControlPath=/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r)
<ub01> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ForwardAgent=yes -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt ub01 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n -u ansible /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-cxuzmrsbxdvydelfnjrsmgvocgkeptxd; /usr/bin/python /tmp/ansible-tmp-1485919043.94-240537002849590/git.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
<ub01> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<ub01> SSH: ansible.cfg set ssh_args: (-o)(ControlMaster=auto)(-o)(ControlPersist=60s)(-o)(ForwardAgent=yes)
<ub01> SSH: ansible_password/ansible_ssh_pass not set: (-o)(KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no)(-o)(PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey)(-o)(PasswordAuthentication=no)
<ub01> SSH: ANSIBLE_TIMEOUT/timeout set: (-o)(ConnectTimeout=10)
<ub01> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_common_args: ()
<ub01> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_extra_args: ()
<ub01> SSH: found only ControlPersist; added ControlPath: (-o)(ControlPath=/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r)
<ub01> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ForwardAgent=yes -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r ub01 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /tmp/ansible-tmp-1485919043.94-240537002849590/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
fatal: [ub01]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "/usr/bin/git clone --origin origin '' /home/ansible/project/mezzanine-example",
    "failed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "accept_hostkey": true,
            "bare": false,
            "clone": true,
            "depth": null,
            "dest": "/home/ansible/project/mezzanine-example",
            "executable": null,
            "force": false,
            "key_file": null,
            "recursive": true,
            "reference": null,
            "refspec": null,
            "remote": "origin",
            "repo": "git@github.com:lorin/mezzanine-example.git",
            "ssh_opts": null,
            "track_submodules": false,
            "umask": null,
            "update": true,
            "verify_commit": false,
            "version": "HEAD"
        },
        "module_name": "git"
    },
    "msg": "Cloning into '/home/ansible/project/mezzanine-example'...\nPermission denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.",
    "rc": 128,
    "stderr": "Cloning into '/home/ansible/project/mezzanine-example'...\nPermission denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n",
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/ansible/playbooks/git.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
ub01                       : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

---

### Update

Thanks to the answer from @Jakuje and other articles, understood that the SSH agent listens on a UNIX socket file. The filename is stored in SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable. However, the SUDO eliminates the environment variables, hence the sudo-ed SSH client does not know how to talk to SSH agent. Therefore, cannot pass the SSh authentication.

- [Understanding ssh-agent and ssh-add](http://blog.joncairns.com/2013/12/understanding-ssh-agent-and-ssh-add/)
- [SSH Definitive Guide 6.3. SSH Agents](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch06_03.htm#ch06-73241.html)
- [An Illustrated Guide to SSH Agent Forwarding](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html)

The solution is in the articled provided by @Jakuje.

[image]

Comment: output of `ansible --version` please, also output of `ansible -m shell -a "ssh-add -L" -kKuansible ub01`

Comment: and also, is your ssh-key for auth and ssh-key for git the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you forward `ssh-agent` socket, it is created with the privileges of the user who is connecting. `become` later makes `ansible` to change the user to some different user (`ansible`) using `sudo`, which causes:

- The target user does not have access to the forwarded socket
- The environment variable "holding the connection" to the agent socket is not preserved during `sudo`

If the target user is `root`, the first should not be a problem. The second problem can be resolved by modifying `/etc/sudoers` on the server to have a line

```
 Defaults    env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
```

It is further explained in the [post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124140/ssh-agent-forwarding-with-ansible).

To overcome the second problem will be more complicated, because you don't want to have your forwarded socket available to all users. Did you consider connecting directly as a user `ansible`?